# hive incorrect header check

Tags: hadoop, hive, gzip

I want to query from a .gz file which i had imported to hive table but when i use some queries which require Map-reduce job for example:
select count(*) from test;
it shows below errors:

```
 java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.decompress(ZlibDecompressor.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:105)
```

I checked and  found that Z LIB is a default compressor codec.
I tried with **bzip** file and it was OK.
but how can i use .gz file.
how can I change the default codec that can support the gz file?

Comment: Use this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-474) as reference.It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, in my case the issue was the files on the folder are of different formats like few were csv and others were parquet. once I keep single file format the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same error, although I can read initial few records, but count no. of records failing with same error.

I solved the problem just by renaming my plain (un-compressed) file to .txt. Previously my file name was ; I renamed it to .txt. Also if you un-compress any file test you can read data from it.

And if you want to test run count number of records as explained above, it will do complete scan which will tell you exactly if data is loaded correctly or not.

I posted this solution at one other place